# Why 'set' data structure is told to be unordered?

Tags: data-structures

Well, I think it's perfectly ordered, because position of the elements depends on their hash function, thus if that objects are immutable, then after you put them in the set, their position will remain unchanged. And everytime you, say, print your set you'll have exact the same elements order. Sure, you can't predict their position until their hash function is calculated, but anyway.

Comment: "Unordered" does not mean "changes order each time", it means "have no control over and cannot necessarily predict the order (from a user perspective)"...

Comment: @deceze thanks, where actually you've got this definition from?

Comment: @deceze ah. I just saw that quotations and tried to find it.

Answer (score 4):

### Generic / abstract data type

The definition of *set* from *Aho, Hopcroft, Ullmann*: 'Data Structures and Algorithms', Addison-Wesely, 1987:

> A set is a collection of members (or elements); [...] . All members of a set are different, [...]

The abstract data type *set* does not have the characteristic of *ordered* or *unordered*.
There are some methods defined which operate on a set - but none of them has something to do with ordering (e.g see *Martin Richards*: 'Data Structures and Algorithms').

Two sets are seen equal, if each element from one set is also inside the other - and there are no additional elements.

When you write down a set (and therefore all the elements of a set) you need to write them down in some order.  Note that this is just a representation of the appropriate set.

Example: A set which contains the elements one, two and three can be written down as {1, 2, 3}, {1, 3, 2}, {3, 1, 2} and so on.  These are only different representations of the same set.

### Specific implementations

In different programming languages *sets* are implemented in different ways with different use cases in mind.

In some languages (like python, JAVA) the standard set implementations do not expose ordering in their interfaces.

In some languages (like C++) the standard set implementation exposes ordering in their interfaces.

Example (C++):

> Internally, the elements in a set are always sorted from lower to higher following a specific strict weak ordering criterion set on container construction.
>
> template < class Key, class Compare = less,
>              class Allocator = allocator > class set;

(see [C++ set](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/set/)).

Comment: @Andreas, the question wasn't specific about any language, but I had Python in mind.

Comment: @muistooshort: With this answer I want to hint the author of the question to be more precise, because the question is wrong (in some contexts the set data structure is told to be ordered). In the mean time the author added more information.  With this information and your hint I'll try to reformulate my answer.

Comment: Yeah, the update makes sense. Sorry for the delay, I had to sleep and work in the middle of all this.

Comment: @AndreasFlorath, thank you for including the reference to Aho et al., but I'm not able to reconcile this definition with the one provided in the Python docs: "A set is an **unordered** collection with no duplicate elements" - why do they say unordered?

Answer (score 2):

The hash function is not (usually) an externally visible or modifiable parameter of a set; moreover, even if you have an implementation where the hash function is known and well characterized, you can't specify the behavior when hash values collide.

The usual summary of this is that the *implementation* of the set may impose an order, but the *interface* does not.

Comment: -1: depending on the language (which is not specified) and the implementation (which is not specified) the set might be ordered and there might be even no hash function available for the elements.

Comment: @AndreasFlorath: True, but in the absence of language information it is inappropriate to make *any* assumption, positive or negative, about it.

Answer (score 2):

To which definition of set are you referring? In my understanding, «set» is a name for a data structure that contains a number of unique elements and usually allows addition and deletion. Everything else is not guaranteed and may be subject to implementation.

It doesn't say there is no order, but there is no specific order for every valid implementation. The use of hashtables is common, but using any type of list or tree is also possible.

So the order might be through a hashfunction (already lots of possible implementations), or related to order of addition or ...

Comment: actualy I took my definition from here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=x7ARbhM7kuw it's lecture from one of the Udacity courses.

Comment: also wikipedia says: "In computer science, a set is an abstract data structure that can store certain values, without any particular order, and no repeated values." We maybe don't see it or control it, but there is an order!

Answer (score 2):

After you add a new element to HashSet, it gets modified and the new element may get positioned anywhere depending on the hash value calculation. Thus the previous order is not maintained.