# DART - Why 'set' data structure is told to be unordered?

Tags: dart

I see in dart tutorial's websites that ((A set is an unordered collection of values. We can’t get the values by their index values as they are unordered.)) but we can:

```
main(List<String> args) {
Set a = Set();
a.add(10);
a.add(20);
a.add(40);
a.add(50);
var p = a.elementAt(0);
print(p);
}
```

so what is the meaning of the unordered collection??
I see Andreas Florath's Answer too :
[Why 'set' data structure is told to be unordered?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10310608/why-set-data-structure-is-told-to-be-unordered)
but I didn't understand.
can anyone help to understand what's the meaning of unordered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on the type of Set, it might be one that optimizes for preserving order, or it might be one that optimizes for look-up speed, or it might be one that optimizes for insertion speed.  You can't get all three at once.  Take a look at each of the "implementors" in the Set documentation (https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Set-class.html), which also says:

> A HashSet is unordered, which means that its iteration order is
> unspecified, LinkedHashSet iterates in the insertion order of its
> elements, and a sorted set like SplayTreeSet iterates the elements in
> sorted order.

Comment: tnx for  Answer . but why we say : We can’t get the values by their index? but in above example, we can ?

Comment: The set doesn't have an index, but if the set retains order, you can get a consistent `.toList()`, and do your indexing ops there.

Comment: Also, .elementAt() for Set simply runs the iterator that many steps forward, and is very inefficient.  So if you ask for .elementAt(20), and then .elementAt(19), you've walked 19 elements twice.  Ugh!

Comment: Sets do indeed not promise an efficient `elementAt` (and rarely have one), and sets *in general* do not promise anything about order being preserved when adding or removing elements. If you have a set and iterate it repeatedly without changing it, it *should* have a consistent iteration order, but if you add just one element, it might completely change the order of elements afterwards. Specific set implementations may promise more, like `LinkedHashSet` preserving insertion order and `SplayTreeSet` preserving `Comparator` order. That's just them, not the general `Set` interface.